# How to create TCP server on Arduino UNO WiFi?

Tags: tcpip, arduino-uno-wifi-dev-ed

I'm currently trying to make my Arduino UNO WiFi work as a TCP host, so I can send him a TCP message and it sends a response.

I had no problem doing this on the Arduino Galileo Gen 2 using the EthernetServer, but since this one is using WiFi, EthernetServer isn't an option.

I can, however, run a web server, but that's not what I want.

So how do I make the Arduino receive, handle and respond to sent TCP/IP messages?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ethernet and wifi are basically the same thing but only joinig Ethernet is codewise different than joining a wifi address and thus these two need 100% different code because wifi and Ethernet are a different thing.

See, compare codes in below links, and you see the difference is on making up the level 1 connection, and tcp and ip on 2 and 3 do not change.

https://github.com/evothings/evothings-examples/blob/master/examples/arduino-led-onoff-tcp/arduinoethernet/arduinoethernet/arduinoethernet.ino

https://github.com/evothings/evothings-examples/blob/master/examples/arduino-led-onoff-tcp/arduinowifi/arduinowifi/arduinowifi.ino

Comment: Thank you, however I'm still getting the "WiFi shield is not present". May I ask you how I can fix that issue? I've tried a lot of things but I still get that error. And is it still neccesary to give the SSID and password if the Arduino Uno WiFi is already connected to the wifi?

Comment: To initialize the used connection object, I suppose yes.

Comment: Okay thanks. Now I'll try to fix the "WiFi shield is not present" message

Answer (score 1):

For Arduino UNO Wifi, you have to use library "UnoWiFi-Developer-Edition-Lib". You can directly download and install it through library manager or can get it offline through the following link "https://github.com/arduino-libraries/UnoWiFi-Developer-Edition-Lib".

Hope this can help you.

Comment: this 'late' answer is ok, only there is now a better option then the slow UnoWiFi-Developer-Edition-Lib. the new library for Uno WiFi is UnoWiFiDevEdSerial1 library